# Mac OS 10.15 sudo does not work

Tags: macos, sudo

Sudo command does not work:

```
Peters-MacBook-Pro.local:~ peter$ sudo vi
Password:
Sorry, user peter is not allowed to execute 'usr/bin/vi' as root on Peters-MacBook-Pro.local.
```

root account is also not working. 
I made "Enable Root User" and changed the password, but the su command does not work.
Rights to the /private/etc folder checked:

`drwxr-xr-x  87 root  wheel  2784 Apr 20 14:42 etc`

There is a suspicion that the problem appeared after disabling SIP (I tried to enable it - it didn't help).

How can I solve this problem? I don't want to reinstall the OS - a lot of things are installed

Comment: Reinstalling macOS does not delete any data. There is an option to reinstall macOS from macOS Recovery which does not replace or delete any of your personal files. This probably won't help but try checking the /etc/sudoers file. If you are going to edit, make sure to use ```sudo visudo```.

Comment: Also, I am on macOS Catalina and I am unable to reproduce the error (even with SIP disabled/enabled).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see `cat /etc/sudoers` - permission denied((

Comment: Are you doing this from an administrator account? Have you edited the /etc/sudoers file?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue after making changes to the `/etc/sudoers` file. I commented the following row `%admin ALL = (ALL) ALL` and exited the file. Subsequently, any sudo command resulted in an error message like this: "Sorry, user username is not allowed to execute '/bin/cat /etc/sudoers' as root on macintosh.local."

To resolve this issue, I took the following steps:

- Enabled the root user following the instructions at [How to enable the root user or change the root password on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012)
- Entered root mode using the command `su root`
- Fixed the sudoers file using the command `visudo -f /etc/sudoers`

I hope this helps someone facing a similar problem.

Comment: (Might be worth adding a reminder to disable root mode once again when you've finished?)